# Make DataFrame balanced with respect to a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in Python that looks as follows.

```
  Text  Label
0  abc      0
1  def      1
2  ghi      1
3   .       .
4   .       .
5   .       .
```

There are 100 rows with label '1' and only 50 with label '0'. I would like to have a balanced set so that there are 50 rows with label '0' and 50 rows with label '1'. It does not matter which rows with label '1' that get thrown away.

Is there any concise way of writing this in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `head`:

```
df = df.groupby('Label').head(50)
```

This will take the first 50 from each subset of rows where Label is 0 and 1 respectively. In the case of rows with Label 1, the first 50 are picked, and the rest discarded.

To pick the last 50, replace `head(50)` with `tail(50)`.

To pick 50 rows at random, use `apply` + `sample`:

```
df = (df.groupby('Label', as_index=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=50))
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Note, if any of the groups have lesser than N (=50) items, this will not work.

Comment: I was about to suggest a solution with `.sample` but this is way cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to use head:

```
DataFrame.head(50)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html#